# Perl: From windows,SSH to a linux server?

Tags: windows, linux, perl, ssh

In perl, how do you ssh from windows to a linux server? Not from a command line.

I'm writing a program that will ssh to a linux server from a windows machine.

I know this is a very small description, but I don't know any other way to describe what I'm asking. It's very simple.

UPDATE: If there is a language that is much simplier and/or easy to use, please let me know.

Comment: If there is another language that is better for this situation, please let me know.

Comment: The first hit on Google for "perl ssh" is for Net::SSH::Perl. Tried that?

Comment: The easiest language to use will probably be the one you're comfortable working with, assuming it's a common enough language to have sufficient tools developed for it.  Perl is an excellent choice if you know Perl.  And Net::SSH from CPAN is a good place to start.